# Make a renderer's background transparent but not shapes three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using three.js where I'm showing a static background image and having a renderer animate shapes on top of it. The reason for doing this is to freely rotate the shapes' renderer without affecting the image. The problem is that the background sits behind the renderer so my question is, is it possible to make the renderer's "background" transparent (allowing the shapes to still show) in order to fully see the background image?

Things I've tried:

- Setting opacity on renderer's domElement
- Setting transparency for rgba with renderer's setClearColor method

Here's a simplified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7McS2/) and you'll see that the square (thus renderer) is covering the background.

```
var square = new THREE.Shape();
square.moveTo(0, 0);
square.lineTo(0, length);
square.lineTo(length, length);
square.lineTo(length, 0);
square.lineTo(0, 0);

var geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(square);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
    color: 'rgb(59, 89, 152)',
    opacity: 1,
    transparent: true
});

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.position.x = 50;
mesh.position.y = 50;
scene.add(mesh);

// and the camera
scene.add(camera);

renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to set the `webGLRenderer` `alpha` parameter.

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } );
```

You can leave the clear color at the default value.

```
renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 ); // the default
```

Updated fiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/7McS2/3/ or http://jsfiddle.net/7McS2/4/

three.jr r.63

Comment: OH MY GOODNESS! You are a life saver! I see that I was missing the option "alpha: true" when I initiated the renderer. Didn't realize I had to set that and I was wondering why setting alpha in the ClearColor method didn't work. THANKS!!!

Comment: The transparency breaks as soon as you apply any post processing with EffectComposer...

Comment: Yeah - great solution for static backgrounds. Not sure how this affects performance, but other solutions that set up a different scene just to render the background seem like overkill. (unless you are using EffectComposer apparently.)